# Excel VBA sql queries return wrong value for one column (increases value by 1)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm using Excel sheets as tables. When I run a sql query, one of the columns ends up being incorrect. The query adds 1 to each value. For example, if the value in the column is 6, the query returns 7; if the value is 23, the query returns 24.

Here is the query:

```
sSQL = "SELECT distinct Competency, CInt(Sequence), Item, CInt(RowNr),
                        CInt(Item_RowNr), CInt(Comp_LastRowNr), CInt(Comp_NrItems) 
          FROM [QueryData$] where Comp <> '' 
         order by Competency, Cint(RowNr), CInt(Sequence)"
```

The query returns all the correct info except that Comp_LastRowNr is actually the Comp_LastRowNr + 1. For example, this query returns the following values for `Comp_LastRowNr: 7, 10, 16, 19, 21, 24` even though it's clear the values are `6, 9, 15, 18, 20, 23`.

TIA for any assistance

[image]

Added image with SQL and the results:
[image]

Comment: The query shown doesn't include `Comp_LastRowNr`

Comment: You are correct. That was a typo on my part. I've corrected it. It is included in the SQL string.

Comment: Is column formatted to not display decimal? Could data have decimal part? Review https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/cint-function/

Comment: No decimals. These values are created using the Row() function in a spreadsheet. All whole numbers. I've even formatted as # with 0 decimal places.

Comment: Does `SELECT DISTINCT Comp_LastRowNr` on its own return the correct values ?

Comment: It does not. I checked for values after the decimal and they are all 0.

Answer (score 0):

While not the answer to why this is happening, I was able to work around it by adding values in 2 columns to get the info I need.

Thanks for the suggestions and assistance.